# Working with MS Teams Webinars Graph REST API v1

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Per this article the support of teams live events ends on September 24. [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-teams-live-events-api-on-microsoft-graph/#:~:text=However%2C%20after%20September%2030%2C%202024,working%20after%20September%2030%2C%202024](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-teams-live-events-api-on-microsoft-graph/#:%7E:text=However%2C%20after%20September%2030%2C%202024,working%20after%20September%2030%2C%202024).

Because of this I'm using the new Graph REST Api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/virtualeventsroot-list-webinars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-headers
to query for webinars.

However, the only count parameter works and no other:

```
var result = await graphClient.Solutions.VirtualEvents.Webinars
.GetByUserIdAndRoleWithUserIdWithRole("organizer", "00b1190f-0000-4c95-0000-c4d2d852812b").GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true;
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 2;
});
```

I want to get only 'Published' webinars and with a startdatetime of today and greater. I've tried doing simple filters but none are working. Can someone please help?

```
var result = await graphClient.Solutions.VirtualEvents.Webinars
    .GetByUserIdAndRoleWithUserIdWithRole("organizer", "1000090f-0000-4c95-0000-c4d2d852812b").GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Count = true;
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 2;
        // requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter =
        //     "date(startDateTime/dateTime) ge 2024-03-26T12:00:00Z";
        // requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter =
        //     "startDateTime/dateTime ge '2024-03-26T12:00:00Z'";
        
      requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "startswith(displayName, 'Test')";
    });
```

Comment: According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/virtualeventsroot-list-webinars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#optional-query-parameters), it seems like this method supports the `$count` OData query parameter only.